# copying unsigned char array to pointer

Tags: pointers, hex

I am trying to hash the data string and then copy the result to a pointer in order to use it elsewhere (send it over a URL). Problem is that although hash is correct the pointer does not contain the correct hash.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
   char data[] = "oNOH0hwZ3H6aduK5hnhxl5CI5C9v1EAghfO8maYfHUgKfQGn3NLeJdNEGNZyhqFpvjoIkcOSXUt2BZfvDQAcUeHqRxOZNke9ttHEvmmi7FbzugUXXl0HpxY7UDWyN1x6k5AGhNPfiQECXpqKAgiQE6NpzANcsb9D6AaedPklwOOk35Vtc3aGZOWoezrxBq1xR1CUHM63rLekGZEJSEgIi2XnreLSvCgctJX1mUVDvZO2OjBxOI6XATaSYMBjeImyh9puUaYfZC8ELA2p8YdyHdgvQIFUgRjoRyICzwHpZGUB6MR5BUu9YBvE90pfIytqX2SmoqCeXmFUZmPq79pVAKqzBFFa3YrRQa35rw9eIFYxSEOPE3B4ERu6m07gOoXvpRrGeqKMWzaE3OkxILsdtN9GD7MimAEBiV7mcIZY7Zt1EDpcfHfylf4PcHYp8sQhdNugmj4j9naDRpFWXLk9QeOTMC8KUPSYtc4FmZOldPOU4kGSVQRCVwmxYk8J0QyjTtO5ithm8W636CLSitl4QxsFIrfy7DIRXmM6FTiEFexCG9lPtwK9U2EsjJRhcpY0BBW7l4BR8ZjFYvlhRVgBNKUWjB4mRTcjkZgwTIdSxnnmIytqjASXbCKk4ExLnAUyp1U8AXRYa4aJtuZDUHqVa064vuGIUq69iR8IEPwFKxe4R4yBCPnCFkx1E3zokwosdn1I3odDLiytdWVFB887ivYMoo1yLfRPsJnlXrPzAeTD1E9tD7rLtgoIuf76lOLEoYQcgwCGAl9sP9Li73Uq98ZueWqqB2VPRBRXYjtpvtHasjjpc3Gc2vw7iNoJF9omB69pgsFBLdC4mLkpFRrycOvkrJUWJ98a57qcqWD2Z6XbI7rdOJCRnX2ExMq6Lp7HnoJDadwZaj1IgjMVSeC52uAp7QmJ6kgjzQNzT9pTihspq4b98D50YvgWctv8DCh2iUs2TIL2P4i6Yj5XN0OCmUooeKmHctAkeTcYrOQ6IZ2x9YkNPZf1KufO5rm7LMiP";
   unsigned char hash[SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
   SHA512(data, sizeof(data) - 1, hash);


   for(int i = 0; i < SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
    printf("%02x", hash[i]);
   }

   unsigned char* phash = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(hash));
   memcpy(phash, hash, (sizeof(hash)));
   printf("\nHash is: %p", *phash);

   //some other code here
```

}

OUTPUT:a5274651e4573a7fea8dc1936a26a77a0667f600cad6c0afdd648431fa44b9e1e9128237b8012f103218f743cc422214701af609d22f9cbdf78e7bd5b374b87b (correct hash)
Hash is : 0x564e7a3dc670

What am I missing here?

Comment: You can't pass your hash to functions which expect a c-string.

Comment: So how can I copy the hash into a pointer to actually use next? Can you elaborate on what you mean with that?

Comment: `strlen` is for c-strings, you can't use it for your hash. Just use `sizeof`. And the `+1` is unnecessary. Its not a c-string, so sticking a NUL at the end doesn't help.

Comment: Edited the post, using sizeof didn't solve the problem. I think it has something to do with the size of phash, as I always end up with 8 characters instead of 164

Comment: If you're talking about the second `printf`, the result is different because you're doing it wrong. Check how you printed it the first time and how you try to print it the second time.

Comment: The first time I print the first two characters in hex and that works for the hash I get from SHA512 function. The second time I do exactly the same. The only difference as far as I know, is that in the first printf i only use the elements of the array where on the second I print the pointer. I don't see what would be wrong with that. Can you provide a hint? Thanks.

Comment: The difference is that you're not dereferencing the pointer the second time.

Comment: I edited the post for the second printf. Hash (pointer) is now 0xa5. I notice that a5 is the first element of the hash array. However, shouldn't the pointer contain all the data from the hash array? Sorry for the number of questions, but I don't understand what is wrong this implementation.

Comment: You're only printing the first `unsigned char` of the hash. Again, compare your first printf with your second.

Comment: The first one is an array and the second one is a pointer. When we do this with characters it works: char 
str[]="abcd";
char* pstr;
strcpy(pstr, str); 

Why is it different here? Shouldn't I be getting the whole data on pointer and not the first one, right?

Comment: But your hash isn't a c-string, so it doesn't work without a loop.

Comment: So what's the point in using a pointer if I have to loop over again? This is why it is frustrating.